# Overriding multiple generic functions with a single function with common upper bounds

Tags: java, generics, overriding, upperbound

I have two different interfaces

```java
interface ColumnSet {
   <V, I extends Column & Input<V>> V getValue(I column);
}

interface ParameterSet {
   <V, I extends Parameter & Input<V>> V getValue(I value);
}
```

where the types `Column` and `Parameter` are simply marker interfaces to stop `Column`s being used where `Parameter`s should be and vice-versa. Behind the scenes I would therefore like to have a single class that implements them both as follows:

```java
class ObjectSet implements ColumnSet, ParameterSet {
   @Override public <V, I extends Input<V>> V getValue(I input) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Logically it seems like `ObjectSet.getValue` should be a valid override for both `ColumnSet.getValue` and `ParameterSet.getValue` as it takes any `Input<V>` as an argument which is upper bounded by both `Column & Input<V>` and `Parameter & Input<V>`. However Java 9 doesn't recognise it as overriding either of them reporting `The method getValue() of type ObjectSet must override or implement a generic supertype method`.

Is this a limitation of generics in Java or am I missing something fundamental?

(Obviously I can't create two separate methods in `ObjectSet` due to them having the same erasure, which leaves me with the alternative of giving different names for the two `getValue` methods in the interfaces which I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: I compile with no error by adding both method `<V, I extends Column & Input<V>> V getValue(I column);` and `<V, I extends Column & Input<V>> V getValue(I column);`in `ObjectSet`.

Comment: Ah, so in my original example I had `Column/Parameter` and `Input` swapped. If you write `Column & Input<V>` and `Parameter & Input<V>` everywhere then you are allowed to add both methods. If you instead you write `Input<V> & Column` and ` Input<V> & Parameter` everywhere you are not allowed to add both methods because type erasure only uses the first bound and not the second.

That gives me a way to proceed, thanks! I'm still interested about why the original approach doesn't work.

Comment: I've just realized how to avoid your problem and also decouple `ObjectSet` from `ColumnSet`, `ParameterSet`, and from all other kinds of settings sets that can ever be created. Check out my answer I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [(§8.4.8.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1), *an instance method `m1` overrides another instance method `m2` if the signature of `m1` is a subsignature [(§8.4.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) of the signature of `m2`*.

In other words, the overriding method signature should be *the same as either overridden method signature or erasure [(§4.6)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) of the overridden method signature*.

So overridden method parameters can't be replaced with parameters of a less specific type in the overriding method. You can read why this is so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485666/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-not-allowing-supertypes-on-java-method-overrides).

---

In your case, the `ObjectSet#getValue` signature isn't the same as the `ColumnSet#getValue` signature and its erasure signature (`Object getValue(Column column)`). The same goes for `ParameterSet#getValue`.

---

As it was pointed out by [@samabcde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7928721/samabcde) if base methods are declared like this:

```
<V, I extends Column & Input<V>> V getValue(I column);
<V, I extends Parameter & Input<V>> V getValue(I value);
```

You can implement them as follows:

```
@Override
public <V, I extends Column & Input<V>> V getValue(I value) {
    return doGetValue(value);
}

@Override
public <V, I extends Parameter & Input<V>> V getValue(I value) {
    return doGetValue(value);
}

private <V, I extends Input<V>> V doGetValue(I value) { ... }
```

---

And if base methods are declared like this:

```
<V, I extends Input<V> & Column> V getValue(I value);
<V, I extends Input<V> & Parameter> V getValue(I value);
```

You can only implement their erasure as follows:

```
@Override
public Object getValue(Input value) { ... }
```

---

Since neither of these options looks good I recommend redesigning your code the following way:

```
public interface Input<R, V> {
    // ...
}
```

```
public interface ObjectSet<R> {
    <V> V getValue(Input<R, V> input);
}
```

```
public class ObjectSetImpl<R> implements ObjectSet<R> {
    @Override
    public <V> V getValue(Input<R, V> input) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you can easily create `ObjectSet` instances that only accept `Input` with specific type parameter `R`:

```
public interface Column<V> extends Input<Column<?>, V> {}
```

```
ObjectSet<Column<?>> columnSet = new ObjectSetImpl<>();
```

If you dislike writing `ObjectSet<Column<?>>`, you can create a better-named implementation of `ObjectSet<Column<?>>` that delegates all the work to `ObjectSetImpl`:

```
public class ColumnSet extends DelegatingObjectSet<Column<?>> {}
```

```
ColumnSet columnSet = new ColumnSet();
```

Where `DelegatingObjectSet` is:

```
abstract class DelegatingObjectSet<R> implements ObjectSet<R> {
    // you can use dependency injection here
    private final ObjectSet<R> delegate = new ObjectSetImpl<>();

    @Override
    public <V> V getValue(Input<R, V> input) {
        return delegate.getValue(input);
    }
}
```